# RabbitMQ: Preventing jobs to run simultaneously on two different workers

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, pika

I have a Python Django project with two RabbitMQ workers, using the pika lib, which receives jobs to perform actions on a certain Django object which is specified in the request.

The thing is, I don't want the workers, A and B, to perform their actions on the same Django object, x, at the same time as that might cause problems. It doesn't matter which workers goes first but if A is working on x and B receives a job to work on x, I want this job to wait until A is done.

So the problems boils down to being able to know what the other worker is working on and being able to pause a job until a certain time. Note that in my actual project I have more than 2 workers which this must be applied to, I choose two In my example to make it easier to dissect.

Thanks for the help,
Mattias

Comment: This sounds like a job scheduling problem with resource constraints - not sure that RabbitMQ is the best tool for the job.  For instance, if job A runs for 5 minutes locking object X, and 5,000 job B's arrive during job A, your program might blow up.  Can you give a ballpark estimate for the duration of your jobs?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use some locking mechanism, perhaps based on database.

1. When a worker is working on a django object, it marks the work in database. a MySQL example:

   worker_id |  object_id | task_type 
     22          44          3  // entry inserted to mark the work
2. When another worker picks up a django object, it checks that it is not marked as in #1, and proceeds to pick next item.
3. When a worker has finished working on an object, the database lock row is deleted or marked as FINISHED.

Comment: Althrough I second this approach, there are some issues with lock release after abnormal work termination on error/timeout/worker thread death etc

Comment: Ok, this might work but how do I proceed to pick next item, that's the logic I'm not sure of.